# How to make a secret Door(entry)

Tags: modeling

I want to make a secret entry. But it doesn't blend in with the wall. Is there a way to fix this?[image]

Answer (score 2):

i would use boolean modifier for this:

make a cube as big as your door should be, then duplicate that cube.

[image]

on the first cube make this boolean modifier:

Intersect with plane, apply that -> this is your door

[image]

on the plane make this boolean modifier:

difference with duplicated cube -> apply that and you have your surface with a hole.

[image]

now you can animate the door easily:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the easiest way would be to create 3 objects:

- 1: The wall with no door visible
- 2: The wall with a hole
- 3: The door

Then you keyframe the visibility this way:

- First only 1 is visible, and 2 + 3 are invisible:

[image]

- Then, as soon as the doors opens, 1 is invisible, and 2 + 3 are visible:

[image]

There's a more complicated way with only one object and the use of the *Data Transfer* modifier in order to make the door invisible but if the first solution works for you it's better.

Comment: +1 ...but yeah, you know...so your door is just a fake door...it's not a real door....so it's an Amber Heard door....

Comment: maybe that secret door should lead to Batman's cave...what do you think? :D

Comment: wow man I was listening to the Depp trial  ^^

Comment: so you were the only one who is on Amber's side, weren't you? Objection! Hearsay!

Comment: but i cannot believe Johnny won't come back as Captain (!) Jack Sparrow for 1 million alpakas...that's disappointing

Comment: quite funny to follow, but actually I can't believe AH, she looks like the abuser here

Comment: i think 99% of the people don't believe here....her acting in court is just really bad...

Comment: ok but the dog who stepped on the bee   :/

Comment: yeah...that was the hardest thing which ever happened to her....the best thing for me was: pledge and donating is for me the same LOOOOOL ...i hope they will only pledge her acting fee - THAN she will learn the difference!

Comment: Yes the pledge thing was bad for her, but i hope we'll hear the dog and the bee